# Cannot hook up the view because of the Data Context (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, view

So my problem is that, initially I got the following code in my MainWindow.xaml class

```
<Button Margin="10,20,10,10" Height="37" Command="{Binding AddCmd}">View all customers</Button>
....
<TabControl x:Name="myTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding WorkSpaces}" Height="323">
                            <TabControl.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:AllCustomersViewModel}">
                                    <views:AllCustomersView/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </TabControl.Resources>
                            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                                ....
                            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </TabControl>
```

and in the MainWindow.xaml.cs class, I have this code

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new DemoWPFApp.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel();
            myTabs.DataContext = this.DataContext; //that is where the problem is
        }
```

So, basically what I want is that when I click the button "View All Customers" it will add a new AllCustomerViewModel to the list of WorkSpaces, and show the AllCustomerView on the screen.
However, I cannot do this. BUT when I delete the line "myTabs.DataContext = this.DataContext;" in the MainWindow.xaml.cs class, it works !
Can someone explain to me why ? Because I already set my AllCustomerView data context to be AllCustomerViewModel. And I cannot understand why that line is the problem of my application.
Thank you.

Comment: Assuming that `myTabs` is an element in the visual tree of MainWindow, the assignment `myTabs.DataContext = this.DataContext;` seems to be useless in the first place. The DataContext property value is by default inherited by all child elements.

Comment: I see. I was adding them for debugging purpose at first.